# Ratchet PHP: count online users

Tags: javascript, function

I'm using Ratchet PHP for a chat.
I need to be able to display how many users are online.

So in my Chat.php file:

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
{
    $count = $this->clients->count() + 1;
    print_r($count);

    $conn->countClient = $count;

    $this->clients->attach($conn);

    echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
}
```

Since this function is called every time a new connection is made.. I chose to make my count there but... correct me if I'm wrong ;)

```
print_r($count);
```

Give give me 1... even if I have multiple users connected.

But I also struggle with the JS part:

```
<script>

    function connect() {

        var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080?token={{ user.user_id }}');

        // OPEN THE CONNECTION
        conn.onopen = function (e) {
            console.log("Connection established!", );
        };
     }
</script>
```

How can I pass the value count (attach to the conn object in my PHP function) ?

Thanks for any advice or help

Comment: Why don't you just change the function itself to increment the variable?

Comment: @Barmar well can you give ne an example ?
The function I'm talking about is a function "connect", liked to a websocket.

So everytime a new user is connected this function is called, reason why I tought it could be easy to just detect when it's called

Comment: Are you trying to get a count of how many people are connected? or, something else? there may be better ways of accomplishing your goal than monkeypatching, but without more information, it's the only real solution that wouldn't be a wild guess.

Comment: @KevinB this is exactly what I try to do.. I'll edit my question and try to explain

Comment: the client can't directly access that value, so your server will need to broadcast it to the clients.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific maybe ? 
As you see... I'm king of lost :(

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with ratchet php to do more than refer to docs unfortunately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220586/discussion-between-chris-1985-and-kevin-b).